# Removing "Windows is not genuine" warning

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

I get the "Your Windows version might not be genuine" warning, even though I have a legit copy of Windows 7. But I can't enter the product key for some reason (it says "Activation status not available" and "Product ID not available"). Since I don't care about the updates (they destroy more than they repair anyway), I just want to remove the warning after boot and on the desktop. But the tutorials I found (like [this](http://www.winfaq.de/faq_html/Content/tip2000/onlinefaq.php?h=tip2072.htm), [archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20130702140413/http://www.winfaq.de/faq_html/Content/tip2000/onlinefaq.php?h=tip2072.htm)) say I should

- uninstall KB905474 (which is not installed on my computer)
- delete the registry key HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows NT/CurrentVersion/Uninstall/WGA (but the key "Uninstall" doesn't even exist)
- delete C:\Windows\System32\WgaLogon.dll and System32\WgaTray.exe (which both don't exist)
- de-register "LegitCheckControl.dll" (which I also don't have)

Some other tutorials also told me to enter the command SLMGR -REARM, but that gives me the warning "Error 0x80070005", Access denied, action needs higher permissions.

I think you see the pattern: None of the steps of this tutorial work for me and all other tutorials I found just tell me the same as that one. So what can I do? I want an unbothered start and my own desktop background.

It would be great if I could just re-enter the product key, but answers on how to just remove the warning are ok, too.

Comment: Call MS and register properly.

Comment: KB905474 is an update for Windows XP. The relevant one in W7 is [KB971033](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/971033/description-of-the-update-for-windows-activation-technologies).

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to call Microsoft, and they can help you get Windows 7 activated:

[How to contact a Microsoft Product Activation Center by phone](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/950929/get-help-activating-microsoft-windows)

If you attempt to activate Windows 7 (or even access the activation GUI) and receive the message `error 0x80070005 "Access denied"`, try the following:

> 1. Modify the following folders by granting **Full control** permissions to the **Everyone** group:
>
>    ```
>    %SystemDrive%\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft  
>
>    %SystemDrive%\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft
>    ```
> 2. Restart the service **Software Protection**
> 3. Activate with a generic key by opening a command prompt and entering the following:
>
>    ```
>    slmgr.vbs /ipk 489J6-VHDMP-X63PK-3K798-CPX3Y
>    ```
> 4. Start the **Activate Now** wizard and enter the correct product key.

([Source](http://panerarichang.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/activation-issue-following-failure.html))

Comment: That page wants me to click "activate Windows now", but the button is missing. It says "Status not available. Product ID not available".

Comment: Try to [open the Start Menu, and type **slui.exe 4** and press **Enter**](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/18715-activate-windows-7-phone.html).  Hopefully that works, but if not I have seen numerous sources that say their primary Windows activation line is (888) 571-2048.

Comment: I'm in Germany.

Comment: With slui.exe I get error 0x80070005 "Access denied". There is a link that says I can activate Windows via phone, but it just opens a help window that says I should ask a friend.

Comment: A [contributor on the TechNet forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7e4ff1a1-f962-4696-947d-79b635bb6425/activation-windows-7-fails-with-error-0x80070005?forum=w7itproinstall) says that they encountered the same problem and implemented the solution from this page successfully:  [Activation Issue - Code: 0x80070005](http://panerarichang.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/activation-issue-following-failure.html).

Comment: Thank you, @Run5k, that blog article solved it for me! The Microsoft support gave up after an hour, saying that my system can't be rescued and has to be reinstalled. Then I read your comment and solved it in 3-5 minutes. Can you please post it as an answer so that I can set it as best answer?

Comment: Glad to hear it!  I will update the answer accordingly.